# should a web server throw an exception for an invalid request?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, webserver

I have built an web app that retrieves files based on an given ID. If the servers throw an exception for an invalid ID, will this stop the server? (I've tried it in my localhost, the sever seems to be fine after an exceptoin is thrown, but I am still unsure because the browser even renders the pages after I stop the server in visual studio.)

I am doing this because I want to have a way to tell the client application, who accesses my web app via a http GET formatted as hostname/get/id, if a file can be retrieved. The server returns a FilePathResult (in C#) for a valid ID. For invalid ID, is there a better way than throwing an exception?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a method return a boolean after checking the client id then redirect to a diff page explaining the results.

Comment: i did show user an error on the webpage when a human is trying to download the file by entering a fileID. but now I am dealing with another program trying to download the file on behalf of the user (i provided an url pattern just for the program). is throwing an exception appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general an exception thrown by your code will result in an HTTP 500 response.  Depending on server configuration the result will be either a standard error page or an extended error report with details on the exception - stack trace, etc.  Normally you don't want the end users to see these things.

With an MVC application there are two basic ways to handle reporting failure in this type of code.

First you can throw an [`HttpResponseException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception.aspx) with an appropriate HTTP response code:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

The other option is to change the return type of your controller method to [`ActionResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx) and return a different type of result on failure.  This is useful for example when you want to return a full redirect, an error view, etc.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fname)
{
    string filepath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fname);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
        return new RedirectResult("~/Some/Error/Page");
    return new FilePathResult(filepath, "text/plain");
}
```

Of course that's just a massive simplification.  Basically using `ActionResult` as a return type means you can return any derivative of that class, including your `FilePathResult`, a `ViewResult` (from the `View` method for instance) or any of the others.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! do you think it's good practice to throw HttpResponseException when a program is accessing, while doing a redirect for a human?

Comment: Personally I prefer not to use it, but the MVC framework is setup to accept those exceptions as valid outputs.  It's a style choice I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception will not stop the web server.